# Can I record a phone call on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, audio, call

Nothing more to say than "Is there an app to record the current phone call ?" :-)

Comment: Just for completeness you might want to include your iPhone model and iOS version, just in case.

Comment: Actually, I don't have one yet :-) But, if the answer to this question is Yes. Then, I probably consider the investment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/731/is-an-iphone-call-recorder-theoretically-possible?

Comment: @Dori dun think it's a duplicate, but it is closely related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Beware of legal issues.

You can but you'll need to jailbreak, use extra hardware (plug a mic into the headphone jack), or use 3rd party SIP software. For example, Google Voice has an iPhone app, and Google Voice supports call recording. Google Voice *does* announce to both parties that it is recording the call.

Comment: More info on the jailbreak helping this, please? I could never find any app there to do it (other than 3rd parts that need to call a number).

Comment: If people are going to cite jailbreaking as a "cure-all", can you please include links or relevant information in your answer? Jailbreaking, in and of itself, is not a *solution*. It simply plays the groundwork. But additional software is *always* required. That additional software is the key. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know 3rd-party, Apple-sanctioned apps - ones you'd find in the App Store, jailbroken apps notwithstanding - do not have access to the phone beyond dialing.  In other words you won't find anything in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have Google voice account and download there app.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info, such as more details about how to set up the account and/or download the app (adding a link would be useful). Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.