# How to record phone conversation in iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an app to record the current phone call?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/is-there-an-app-to-record-the-current-phone-call)

How to record phone conversation in iPhone 4?

Comment: clarify : You want to record a phone conversation of a conversation you're having with someone in the same room?

Comment: Phone Conversation. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

## Recorder

[Recorder](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284428991&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) lets you record outgoing calls by using a 415 dial-in number, but for a fee ($2/hour, $13/8 hours).

[image]

**[Check it out](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284428991&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) on the iTunes store and purchase it for 99 cents**

Comment: nice app find :)

Comment: But I want to record the conversation of both side.

Comment: And how does this app not do that? My understanding is that by using the 'middleman' that is the 415 number, the 'middleman' records both sides of the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the iPhone SDK switches off the microphone to 3rd party applications during a voice call.  There *may* be applications available if you have a jailbroken phone.

There is products such as [thecallrecordercard](http://www.thecallrecordercard.com/) that may be off assistance, in that they allow you to record voice calls by using your iPhone and their service.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there are significant legal restrictions on recording phone calls, which vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction -- make sure you know what they are and follow them. For example, in most US states, you need to notify the other party they are being recorded and/or get their consent (Google can find you the specifics).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no native or simple way to do this - unlike many other phones.

I believe one option might be *using the speaker* and any voice recorder, such as the Voice Memo built in app. Despite [some limitations](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2719048?threadID=2719048&tstart=0) it could be enough if you don't care about the sound quality.

See if [SpoofApp](http://www.spoofapp.com/) fits your needs. It's one of the first recording call apps out there, as already pointed out in [another possible duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/731/is-an-iphone-call-recorder-theoretically-possible/881#881), and it even moved from being on Cydia to the [Apple Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phone-gangster/id362421294?mt=8). The app is free, the call recording is not as it's a "complicated made simple" service.

If you're fine with recording just VOIP calls, which can be done for free and within your device without needing to call a 3rd party number, try [Mobile VOIP](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobilevoip/id362528311?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is something out there to intercept the conversation on the hardware level using the headphone jack? Some kind of passthrough device you would plug into the headphone jack and then you plug your mic-equipped headphones into said device. There has to be something out like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a service in the past to [record phone conversations](http://www.recordphoneconversation.com)
they were very helpful and did a great job in setting me up with a good solution.